# Why can't my inner class see my outer class object?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class NewGUIStuff{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        NewGUIStuff gui = new NewGUIStuff();
        gui.go();
    }

    class handlesListListeners implements  ListSelectionListener{
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse){
            list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        }
    }
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse){

    }
    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JList list;

        String[] aList = {"alpha","beta","gamma","delta","epsilon","zeta","eta","theta"};
        list = new JList(aList);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new handlesListListeners());
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        frame.setContentPane(scroller);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So my question here is if inner classes can see their outer classes variables and objects, why can't the inner-class `handlesListListeners` see the `list` object I made in `NewGUIStuff` outer class?

Comment: Are they in the same package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-static inner classes can see the outer class *instance* variables and those local variables they were enclosed around (think closures) if those were declared `final` (in case of anonymous inner classes). Those non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to the outer `this` inserted by the compiler and that's how they see the member variables of the outer class. The final local variables you enclose your anonymous class around will be implicitly passed into the a constructor that the compiler will generate for you and stored in the final member fields of the inner class itself.

In your case I see you expect to see a local variable defined in a whole different lexical context, the one your inner class has no knowledge about. Convert it into the outer class member variable and your inner class will see it.

Comment: While all these answers were more or less telling me how, this helped me the most. You saw where I was getting confused about what I was expecting in terms of scope and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, "Your inner class can see the outer class", that isn't your problem.

Your problem is that the `NewGUIStuff` class does not have any member fields for the inner class to see. The `list` variable that you declared is local to the `go` method.

```
public class NewGUIStuff {
    JList list; //this is a member field

    ...

    public void go() {
        ...
        JList list; //this is a local variable
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this is where I had some confusion, if I am creating a new object while in the go() method, shouldn't the inner class see that since the object was created within that method?

Comment: I think I might get what you're saying here. So when the go method finishes everything else, since the listener is still in place but the `go()` method no longer is on the stack, the reference to `list` is gone?

Comment: Yes. The reference to list in the go method is gone. More importantly, the `list` variable was never visible to the inner class. The answer you accepted explains the technical details.

Answer (score 2):

Because the list object is inside the scope of the go() method, not the scope of the NewGUIStuff class. The list object can only be "seen" inside the that same method.

Comment: Thank you, someone gave a little more in-depth explanation where I was getting confused but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` variable is local to the method `go()`. If you want it to be visible you need to make it an instance field of `NewGUIStuff`. Something like this:

```
public class NewGUIStuff {

    private JList list = new JList(); // Member of outer class so in scope from handlesListListeners

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewGUIStuff gui = new NewGUIStuff();
        gui.go();
    }

    class handlesListListeners implements  ListSelectionListener {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is a case where I did not full appreciate the context of variable scope if I am reading what everyone is saying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `list` is a local variable in the `go()` function. It is out of scope for the `handlesListListeners` class.

If `list` were an instance variable of the outer class then the inner class would be able to see it. Alternatively, you could make your inner class local to the `go()` function, too, which would mean that `list` is now in scope:

```
void go() {
    final JList list = ...
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            // list is now in scope
            list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that `list` must be declared to be **final** if it is used in this way.

Comment: Anonymous inner classes are pretty useful. They're generally a good way to go when you're building GUIs.